# Use Nuxt programmatically without builder

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt programmatically inside express with nuxt.render middleware like below

```js
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = require('express')()

const api = require('../api')
app.use('/api', api)

let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

// Init Nuxt.js
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
app.use(nuxt.render)

async function start() {
// Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  console.log('Server listening on ' + host + ':' + port)
}
start()
```

When I am developing the server api routes and make some changes to the server side api files and restart the server, the whole nuxt project builds everytime which takes too much time. This is inconvenient as there were no changes in the nuxt files, only changes in the api route files.

So after building once, I comment out the following lines:

```
if (config.dev) {
// const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
// await builder.build()
}
```

I then restart the server which of course does not start the nuxt builder. But then I am now not able to access nuxt on browser. The server api routes work but the nuxt page routes just show "Nuxt loading…" screen.

How can I use nuxt app in development mode without building it everytime?

Comment: Launch nuxt separately from your backend. Why do u launch it this way? Its a bad idea, and only really rare usecases should be used

Comment: @Aldarund actually it's a valid use case. If one can deploy Nuxt SSG bundle as part of java web server(as static resources), then why not to have nuxt server running as part of the the same process as node based api server? Certain restrictions sometimes don't leave much choice, especially in corporate environments there are often very ridiculous obstacles in terms of server and networking setup. Obviously it's desirable to keep api server separate from UI server, but it is still good to have this flexibility just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a valid use case, sometimes one doesn't want to use two servers for a very small api/ui pair. What I would suggest is also to have a detached mode which works through `nuxt/proxy` and you could run it whenever you are doing dev work. In detached mode your nuxt works separately and api runs also separately and nuxt imitates above setup via `nuxt/proxy. It's very easy to setup via adding smth like this in nuxt config

```js
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/proxy', {    "/api/": { target: 'http://localhost:888/api'} }]
  ]
```

In prod you could run as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`build.parallel`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#parallel), [`build.cache`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#cache), and [`build.hardSource`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#hardsource). This will dramatically speed up your build times after the initial build.

I do **not** recommend this for production builds though. This is how I have it in my code:

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

module.exports = {
// ...
  build: {
    parallel: isDev,
    cache: isDev,
    hardSource: isDev
  },
// ...
};
```

And in the `package.json` I set the `NODE_ENV` to `production` for the `build` script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt build"
}
```

P.S.: You might also need to set [`build.publicPath`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#publicpath) for the dev builds.